# javascript return units, if present when multiplying 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

2 numbers input to my function values are `a, "0.045u"` and `b, "3"`

```
function mult2nums(a,b) {
    var c = null;
    var unitsFora = null;
    var unitsForb = null;
    var cUnits = null;
    //--> issue - unitsFora = ??; // how to strip off units designator
    //--> issue - unitsForb = ??; // how to strip off units designator
    a = isFloat(a); // also works if int
    b = isFloat(b); //
    c = a*b; 
    // add logic to compare unit designators and convert as needed
    return(c+cUnits); // need to return the units, returns a string type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to filter out the units:

```
function mult2nums(a,b) {
    var c = null;
    var cUnits = null;
    var unitRegex = /[A-Za-z].*/g
    var unitsForA = a.match(unitRegex);
    var unitsForB = b.match(unitRegex);
    a = parseFloat(a.replace(unitsForA, ''));
    b = parseFloat(b.replace(unitsForB, ''));
    c = a*b; 
    // add logic to compare unit designators and convert as needed
    return c + cUnits;
}
```

Note that the code uses the first encounter of character as the start position of the unit. It can handle upper/lower case differences, and units with number in it (e.g. m/s^2). You can modify the code further to suit your specific needs.

jsFiddle sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywafx1be/